# Calculate hourly count of process in Hive/Spark/SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive

I am trying to calculate the count of process ran in each hourly slots. My input dataset looks like this.

```
process_id      start_time              end_time
PID10001        2018-08-01 00:00:00     2018-08-01 00:10:00
PID10002        2018-08-01 01:00:00     2018-08-01 00:20:00
PID10003        2018-08-01 00:00:00     2018-08-01 02:30:00
PID10004        2018-08-01 02:00:00     2018-08-01 04:00:00
```

Here is the output what I am trying to obtain from the above input dataset. Tagging each and every process to appropriate hourly time slot based on the start_time and end_time value.

```
process_id      start_time              end_time                hour_slots
PID10001        2018-08-01 00:00:00     2018-08-01 00:10:00     00-01
PID10002        2018-08-01 01:00:00     2018-08-01 00:20:00     01-02
PID10003        2018-08-01 00:00:00     2018-08-01 02:30:00     00-01
PID10003        2018-08-01 00:00:00     2018-08-01 02:30:00     00-01
PID10003        2018-08-01 00:00:00     2018-08-01 02:30:00     02-03
PID10004        2018-08-01 02:00:00     2018-08-01 04:00:00     02-03
PID10004        2018-08-01 02:00:00     2018-08-01 04:00:00     03-04
NULL            NULL                    NULL                    05-06
NULL            NULL                    NULL                    06-07
NULL            NULL                    NULL                    07-08
NULL            NULL                    NULL                    08-09
NULL            NULL                    NULL                    09-10
NULL            NULL                    NULL                    10-11
NULL            NULL                    NULL                    11-12
NULL            NULL                    NULL                    12-13
NULL            NULL                    NULL                    13-14
NULL            NULL                    NULL                    14-15
NULL            NULL                    NULL                    15-16
NULL            NULL                    NULL                    16-17
NULL            NULL                    NULL                    17-18
NULL            NULL                    NULL                    18-19
NULL            NULL                    NULL                    19-20
NULL            NULL                    NULL                    20-21
NULL            NULL                    NULL                    21-22
NULL            NULL                    NULL                    22-23
NULL            NULL                    NULL                    23-00
```

How can we achieve this result in Hive? I am stuck on duplicating the rows for each process_id based on the start_time and end_time. If the end time overlaps in multiple hour windows, each new row should be generated with the respective hour_slots. Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: what is the logic for hour_slots

Comment: hour_slots is divided into 24 (0-23). Each hour belongs to a separate partition slot

Comment: Hos is hours_slot related to start_time and end_time. Based on that we can frame the query...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the hour of start-time and hour of end-time in the hour_slots.
The hour_slots is calculated by extracting the hour from start and end times, and concatenating them together.

```
hive> select pid,start_time,end_time,concat((split((split(start_time,' ')[1]),':')[0]),'-',(split((split(end_time,' ')[1]),':')[0])) hour_slots from test;
OK
PID10001        2018-08-01 00:00:00     2018-08-01 00:10:00     00-00
PID10002        2018-08-01 01:00:00     2018-08-01 00:20:00     01-00
```

Comment: Thank you for trying this. But this is not what I am looking for. Please take a look at the question again.